# Link error while using MinGW compiler (can't find __main)

Tags: c++, mingw, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile a very simple program with MinGW on Windows, but I still got link errors. The program to be compiled is just C++ hello world.

```
Z:\dev>type test.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, just using MinGW's g++ is okay.

```
Z:\dev>g++ test.cpp -o test.exe
Z:\dev>test.exe
Hello World!
```

However, I tried to separate compilation and linking, but failed.

```
Z:\dev>g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o

Z:\dev>ld test.o -o test.exe
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__main'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& s
 <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `atexit'
```

It is obvious that I've missed some libraries. So, I tried to link with several MinGW's libraries, but still no good such as `-lmsvcrt`. I also did `lstdc++`, but still `__main` cannot be found and tons of warning messages.

Could you help me out which libraries should be linked together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `ld`, try using `g++` to link.

Try this:

```
Z:\dev> g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
Z:\dev> g++ -o test.exe test.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `ld` directly unless you know you need it. `g++` will know how to call it properly.

```
g++ -o test.exe test.o
```

Answer (score 1):

use `g++` to invoke the linker, like

> g++ test.o -o test.exe

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Link with `-lgcc` if you need to use `ld`. Otherwise, use `g++` to link.