# MinGW undefined reference to malloc, free, sprintf, _beginthreadex

Tags: c, build, mingw, ld

I'm using MinGW.  I have some code which calls malloc and a few other general purpose functions.  When I type:

```
gcc TestCode.c
```

I get an a.exe file, it works perfect, and I don't get any warnings.

If I type this:

```
gcc -c TestCode.c -o TestCode.o
ld *.o
```

I get a whole bunch of warnings such as:

```
TestCode.o:TestCode.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__main'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `printf'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `_strerror'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `snprintf'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `malloc'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `_strerror'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `sprintf'
TestCode.o:TestCode:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `free'
```

I'm assuming this is an issue with how I'm calling the linker.  As such, I'll only post the code if it isn't clear what the problem is.  I'm hoping this is an easy fix and that I simply forgot to include some super obvious library when linking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link error while using MinGW compiler (can't find __main)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981826/link-error-while-using-mingw-compiler-cant-find-main)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that your `ld` doesn't link any libraries by default.  From your error messages, it looks like you need at least the C runtime and `libc`. Use `gcc` to link to get some handy defaults linked in for you:

```
gcc -c TestCode.c -o TestCode.o
gcc *.o
```

If you *really* want to use `ld` directly, you're going to need to figure out the names of your C runtime library and libc.  For example (assuming libraries named `libcrt` and `libc`):

```
ld *.o -lcrt -lc
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction!  I was able to get it working by including the -lmsvcrt flag on my ld.  Unfortunately, the project build might be too large for us to move away from using ld directly, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: Using gcc as a front-end for the linker shouldn't make any difference.  What do you mean "too large for your to move away from using `ld`"?

Answer (score 1):

As [Carl Norum said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695392/12711), you can pass object files to `gcc` and it'll know it doesn't need to compile them - it just passes them on to the linker (whether or not you're compiling other source files in the same invocation).

And you should probably do that because there's a fair amount of detail that goes into linking in the CRT and windows support libraries (unless you have a very specific need to not use the default runtime).  My current MinGW setup links in the following items along with my object files:

```
crt2.o
crtbegin.o

-ladvapi32 
-lshell32 
-luser32 
-lkernel32 
-lmingw32 
-lgcc 
-lmoldname 
-lmingwex 
-lmsvcrt 

crtend.o
```

Use the `--verbose` option to see how `gcc` links for you.